# What should be done to deal with missing observations ( or outlier observation ) for Viterbi?

Tags: probability, markov-process, hidden-markov-model

I want to use *Viterbi* algorithm, to decode an HMM sequence, but very few observations are missing  in some of the steps or outliers. The hidden states in these steps are assumed to be the same as their previous states (or their adjacent states).

Can anyone tell me how can I set the emission probability in these steps. If I were to use *Baum-Welch* algorithm, what should I do.?

Answer (score 3):

It requires a bit of modification to the original Baum Welch. Shun-Zheng Yu and Hisashi Kobayashi wrote a [paper](http://www.hisashikobayashi.com/papers/Hidden%20Semi%20Markov%20Model%20(HSMM)%20and%20Computational%20Algorithms/A%20Hidden%20Semi-Markov%20Model%20with%20Missing%20Data%20and%20Multiple%20Observation%20Sequences%20for%20Mobility%20Tracking.pdf) about this, where they prove that their implementation of the EM algorithm for this problem of missing observations is correct and thereby produces a maximum likelihood.